# how to define a type alias for a higher kinded type by a scala macro annotation (preferably using quasiquotes)

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise

I develop a scala macro annotation that enriches objects with various definitions ([cf. play form macro](https://github.com/swachter/play-macro-form/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/eu/swdev/play/form/Form.scala)). Amongst other things I want that the object contains the type alias

```
type WFS = FS[_, _, _, _]
```

for a varying number of wildcard arguments.

I already tried to extract the value of a single wildcard type by

```
q"type WFS = FS[_]" match { q"type WFS = FS[$t]" => t }
```

and hoped to use the extracted value in a list of type parameters (e.g. q"type WFS = FS[..$tplist]"). Yet the above statement yields an error:

```
scala> q"type WFS = FS[_]" match { case q"type WFS = FS[$t]" => t }
scala.MatchError: type WFS = FS[_$1] forSome { 
  <synthetic> type _$1 >: _root_.scala.Nothing <: _root_.scala.Any
} (of class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$TypeDef)
    at .<init>(<console>:15)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43
```

Is there another - maybe simpler - way to construct the necessary tree?

Answer (score 0):

The error is printing the actual shape of the value you're matching on, and apparently you need to use the same shape in the matching quasiquote:

```
scala> q"type WFS = FS[_]" match { case q"type WFS = FS[$a] forSome { $b }" => println(s"$a --- $b") }
_$1 --- <synthetic> type _$1 >: _root_.scala.Nothing <: _root_.scala.Any
```

If you want to allow for more parameters, and not just one, you better use `"..$x"` to allow for that:

```
scala> q"type WFS = FS[_]" match { case q"type WFS = FS[..$a] forSome { ..$b }" => println(s"$a --- $b") }
List(_$1) --- List(<synthetic> type _$1 >: _root_.scala.Nothing <: _root_.scala.Any)
```

Wildcards are transformed into existentials — `FS[_]` means `FS[T] forSome { type T }` (for details on existentials, there's the Scala Language Specification, Sec. 3.2.10, under "Placeholder Syntax for Existential Types").
When you write `FS[$a]` in your matching quasiquote, that means "I expect here an application of a type constructor to *one* type argument". But `FS[T] forSome { type T }` is an existential type which **contains** an application of a type constructor to an argument, so the pattern will not match.

To understand that better, and to know how to debug similar problems, it's insightful to look with `showRaw` at the trees generated by the quasiquotes — since these are types, we need type quasiquotes, that is `tq"..."`:

```
scala> showRaw(tq"FS[_]")
res15: String = ExistentialTypeTree(AppliedTypeTree(Ident(newTypeName("FS")), List(Ident(newTypeName("_$1")))), List(TypeDef(Modifiers(DEFERRED | SYNTHETIC), newTypeName("_$1"), List(), TypeBoundsTree(Select(Select(Ident(nme.ROOTPKG), newTermName("scala")), newTypeName("Nothing")), Select(Select(Ident(nme.ROOTPKG), newTermName("scala")), newTypeName("Any"))))))

scala> showRaw(tq"FS[T]")
res16: String = AppliedTypeTree(Ident(newTypeName("FS")), List(Ident(newTypeName("T"))))
```

As far as I understand, matching with a quasiquotes means matching with the corresponding tree. So the above demonstrates the problem I described.

It's unfortunate that quasiquotes don't hide such details of the Scala type system.
That might or might not be a bug of quasiquotes, but I can't comment on that — I do guess it would be cool if one would not need deal with

Comment: Thanks - that was a good observation! Now I tried construct the WFS type by `q"type WFS = FS[..$typeParams] forSome { ..$typeDefs }"` where each `typeParam` was constructed by `tq"${newTypeName(s"C$index")}"` and each `typeDef` by `q"type $typeParam"`. Unfortunately this results in a compiler exception: no-symbol does not have an owner
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.abort(SymbolTable.scala:49)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global.abort(Global.scala:254)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$NoSymbol.owner(Symbols.scala:3248)

Comment: Ouch, that's the equivalent of a NullPointerException for Symbols. Usually, the compiler fills in symbols in trees to say to which definition (symbol) a name points to.
I don't understand (yet) macro annotations enough to give a well-thought comment — I suspect you're better off asking a follow-up question with the source code.